# Hide 1 table show another table and toggle back

Tags: jquery

I got two tables with a lot rows and columns and two buttons. I got the buttons to hide 1 and show another but the tables do not till i push the back button the table go away. here is the code

**html**

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="botton" id="815show" class="btn-success btn btn-md visible">8-15-></button>
          <button type="botton" id="17show" class="btn-success btn btn-md invisible"><-1-7</button>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="17" class="table table-sm visible">...
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="815" class="table table-sm invisible">...
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
table.invisible{ display: none }
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#815show").click(function () {
      $("#815show").switchClass("visible", "invisible", 1);
      $("#17show").switchClass("invisible", "visible", 1);
      $("table#17").switchClass("visible", "invisible", 1, function() {
        $("table#815").switchClass("invisible", "visible", 1);
      });
    
    });
    //To hide the table
     $("#17show").click(function () {
      $("#815show").switchClass("invisible", "visible", 1);
      $("#17show").switchClass("visible", "invisible", 1);
      $("table#815").switchClass("visible", "invisible", 1, function() {
        $("table#17").switchClass("invisible", "visible", 1);
      });
      
       
      });
    
});
```

Comment: At the CSS, try changing `display: none;` to `visibility: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="botton" id="815show" class="btn-success btn btn-md visible">8-15</button>
          <button type="botton" id="17show" class="btn-success btn btn-md invisible">1-7</button>
 </div>
<style>
table.invisible{ display: none }
table.visible{ display: block }
</style>
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="17" border="1" class="table table-sm visible ">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="815" border="1" class="table table-sm invisible">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<script>
$('#815show').on('click',function(){
  $('#17').removeClass('visible');
  $('#17').addClass('invisible');
  
  $('#815').removeClass('invisible');
  $('#815').addClass('visible');
});
$('#17show').on('click',function(){
  $('#815').removeClass('visible');
  $('#815').addClass('invisible');
  
  $('#17').removeClass('invisible');
  $('#17').addClass('visible');
});
</script>
```